# How to create a MVC Route only with a paramter in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

How to create a route with only a single parameter?

Example: A want to call

> //URL: `localhost:43760/NameMyProduct`

My route is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "RouteEvent",
               url: "{productName}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Details", ProductName= UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
```

However, this mode does not works and my return is 404.

My View Is:
//HomeController

```
[Route("/{productName}")]
public ActionResult Index(string productName)
{
    return View();
}
```

or (I'am trying also)
//ProductController

```
[Route("/{productName}")]
    public ActionResult Details(string productName)
    {
        return View("Details", productName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do it like this.

For resolve this, we have to create a `Constraint` in specific route.
This `Constraint` must verify the URL's with single paramter to decide which 
route to use.

Example:

```
public class ProductConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
           return !Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MvcApplication))
                .GetTypes().Where(type => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                .Any(c => c.Name.Replace("Controller", "") == values[parameterName].ToString());
        }
    }
```

And my route like this: (This route must be declared in `routeconig.cs` first the `defaultRoute`;

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "RouteProduct",
    url: "{ProductName}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Procuct",
        action = "Detalhe"
    },
    constraints: new { ProductName = new ProductConstraint() }
);
```

There may be an error when the `ProductName` is the same as the Controller. So, think about it maybe do you have to treat this. (A good idea is to handle in `Constraint` created.

I hope I have helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Route` attribute in your action method in the controller.

You can do it by using an **static action** name like this:

```
[Route("/NameMyProduct")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    // Your code here
}
```

This is going to resolve for:

```
URL: localhost:43760/NameMyProduct
```

Or you can **use an actual product name** in the route

```
[Route("/{productName}")]
public IActionResult Index(string productName)
{
    // You can use product name to get the product details
    // I would actually use product id instead, it depends on what you need        
    return View("ProductDetails", productName);
}
```

This is going to work for:

```
URL: localhost:43760/NameMyProduct1
URL: localhost:43760/NameMyProduct2
URL: localhost:43760/OtherProductName
URL: localhost:43760/Product%20Name%20123 -- With spaces encoded
```

I **suggest using the product id** like this:

```
[Route("/Product/{productId}")]
public IActionResult Index(string productId)
{
    // Your code here to fetch the product details and return the view
    ProductViewModel product = GetProduct(productId);
    return View("ProductDetails", product);
}
```

This will work for:

```
URL: localhost:43760/Product/12345
```

Comment: But, I get 404 yet.

Comment: If I add `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` I get  the error: "The route template cannot begin with a forward slash.

Comment: What view are your trying to return? are you referencing to a specific view? because if you dont put the view name and just use `return View()` it is going to look for the view named as the action name which I suppose you dont have. 

For the routes in the startup.cs file you can just leave the default route:

`app.UseMvc(routes => { routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");});`

Comment: It is exatly your second example. ... [Route("/{productName}")] public IActionResult Index(string productName)... Exatly this.

Comment: Are you returning your view like this?
`return View("ProductDetails", product);`. Otherwise, if you are using the example above (with Index methid name) and you dont specify a view name, it will try to get the view named "Index".

Comment: My return in both views is 404.

Comment: Not sure if the routes defined in the two places are crashing each other, did you try leaving the default route map in the startup.cs file as I mentoned before and using the route attribute only? I just created a project from scratch and works for me, see the code here https://github.com/carlosbocanegra/UsingCustomMVCRoutes/blob/master/Controllers/HomeController.cs

Comment: Me too just created a new project, does not get sucess. rssrss

Comment: It would not be why you used AspNetCore.Mvc?